# express testing - jest one mongo db connection setup

Tags: mongodb, express, jestjs

I'm encountering a challenge while attempting to set up a single MongoDB connection that persists across all my Jest tests. My goal is to establish a single connection to the database to avoid multiple connections being created during the execution of tests.

I've tried a few approaches, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired result:

- Using a Global Setup File: I initially attempted to set up the connection in a global setup file. However, after running the global setup, the connection gets closed, which is not the behavior I'm aiming for.
- Using beforeAll and afterAll: Another approach I explored was using beforeAll to establish the connection before tests and afterAll to close it afterward. However, since tests run simultaneously, this approach resulted in multiple connections being established simultaneously, which is not the intended behavior.
- Using setupFilesAfterEnv: I also experimented with using setupFilesAfterEnv to set up the database connection. However, similar to the previous approach, it resulted in multiple connections being created due to tests running concurrently.

Here's a snippet of my Jest configuration

jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    globalSetup: './tests/setup.js',
    globalTeardown: './tests/teardown.js',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./tests/db_config.js'],
    verbose: true,
    preset: '@shelf/jest-mongodb',
    testTimeout: 30000,
};
```

db.config.js

```js
beforeAll(() => {
    // check if db isn't already connected
    if (mongoose.connection.readyState >= 1) {
        return;
    }
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI_TEST, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
        throw err;
    });
});
afterAll(async () => {
    await mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: If you have a single DB connection for all of your tests _and_ run tests concurrently you'll have all kinds of race conditions - imagine one test is deleting records while another is trying to add them, for example.